# Connection pool has closed, database is not open

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-room

I'm aware that this is usually caused by a multi-threading issue or trying to interact with the database when it's been closed but when trying to do thousands of queries these two `IllegalStateException`s get thrown on some devices:

`The database '/data/user/0/.../databases/database.sqlite' is not open.`

`Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.`

I was running into an issue that when an `Entity` gets added to the database that has the same primary key as an `Entity` already in there, it wouldn't replace the original `Entity` even though there's a replace `OnConflictStrategy`.

The original code that didn't throw these errors:

```
myRoomDatabase.dbDao().insertAllRecords(*it.records)
```

The new code, since the replacement strategy did not work:

```
for (record in it.records)
{
    try
    {
        myRoomDatabase.dbDao().deleteRecordsById(record.id)
    } catch (e: Exception)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    myRoomDatabase.dbDao().insertSingleRecord(record)
}
```

I do not call `.close()` anywhere in the app.

My database is provided via Dagger:

```
@Module
open class RoomModule(val application: Application)
{
    @Volatile private var INSTANCE: MyRoomDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): MyRoomDatabase =
        INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
        }

    private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): MyRoomDatabase
    {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyRoomDatabase::class.java,
            "db.sqlite")
            .openHelperFactory(AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory()) // Prepopulated SQLite file
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() // User never modifies database
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    open fun provideMyRoomDatabase(context: Context): MyRoomDatabase = getInstance(context)
}
```

My `Context` is provided via the `AppModule` using an older version of `Dagger`:

```
@Module
public class AppModule
{
    private Context context;

    public AppModule(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    etc.
}
```

Any idea how I can stop this from happening? Am I using Dagger incorrectly?

Comment: The basic issue that appears to naked eye is that you have not provided any way to get context in the method provideMyRoomDatabase(context: Context), also how are you using "?:" in Kotlin? I thought they were not allowed?

Comment: The code runs fine, I'm providing `Context` in a different `Module`. I'll edit the question.
Re: elvis operator: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator

Comment: Check the full stacktrace. Room compilation errors due to bad schemas show as a database closed exception, but the full trace shows what is wrong with the compilation/schema.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @WoogieNoogie Unfortunately this stack trace never gets thrown on my devices but only some devices that use the app in production. The fact that this only happens on some devices would make me think that there is no problem with the compilation/schema as if it was an issue with that, it would happen on all devices? Perhaps I should be doing this operation within a `@Transaction` method?

Comment: Is room the only database implementation you've used, or did you upgrade from a normal SQL database? Is it possible you missed an edge case in the conversion?

I don't think wrapping things into a transaction will help in this case. 

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I can tell you that you're using Dagger slightly improperly here. Rather than setting a volatile variable and having your database creation method be outside of your `@Provides` method, all of that work should be done *inside* it. No reason to mark things as variables and check for existing, Dagger handles that.

Comment: I am not sure, but since you're using loop to insert instead of varargs, the application may have been closed, before the entire process took place? Is their a possibility? Two more question is that why are you not using varargs? And why don't you use the update method? Transaction can help, if the db is getting closed before the operation ends.